# How can I delegate administrative access to a second Azure AD directory on my subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

On one Azure subscription I have the default AD and a second, newly created one, say "MyCustomerAD."

I would like someone else to be able to manage that MyCustomerAD, giving them access to add, remove users, groups, etc., through the portal.

That someone else has no Azure subscription, but they have a Microsoft Account.

How can I allow that someone else to manage the Azure AD without asking them to buy a subscription, and without making them a co-administrator in my subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do is possible, but here's what I learned in *my* experience with trying to delegate administrative access to a single Azure AD tenant within my subscription.

First, to access the Azure management portal (and manage an Azure AD tenant), you **must** use a login associated with an Azure subscription.  In your case, as it did in mine, it means adding a co-administrator to the subscription.  I understand this might be a non-starter for you, but what I ended up doing was creating a *second* subscription. This avoids having to add a co-administrator to your *primary* subscription.  The (potential) downside is that the co-administrator can spin up billable services in the second subscription.

As Azure account administrator:

1. Create new subscription
2. Create new directory, if necessary (e.g. `mycustomerad.onmicrosoft.com`)
3. Add new user to the directory (e.g. `john.doe@mycustomerad.onmicrosoft.com`) and make this user a `Global Admin`. *This* is the account you will use to delegate admin access to the directory.
4. Change the directory of the new subscription to the new directory. In portal, `Settings -> Subscriptions -> Select Subscription -> Edit Directory`
5. Add new user as co-administrator to the subscription. In portal, `Settings -> Subscriptions -> Administrators`

   - Enter email address of new user
   - Check box of the new subscription

As co-administrator:

1. Go to [manage.windowsazure.com](http://manage.windowsazure.com)
2. Login as new user (e.g. `john.doe@mycustomerad.onmicrosoft.com`)
3. Management portal should provide administrative access to the directory (e.g. `mycustomerad.onmicrosoft.com`)

Comment: Thanks for that comprehensive response. I ended up doing something similar myself for demo purposes, under the assumption that I might be able to find some better way later. I think for now this method is probably the best way to do it, but I think the Azure AD team may move Azure AD to Resource Manager, so future readers of this solution may need to check the current status. This would be excellent if this happened soon. It seems that Azure AD has some major enhancements ahead, with Azure ACS basically being decommissioned in favour of new functionality, yet to be released.

Comment: On a related note, I wonder, perhaps it would not make any difference if AD was in Resource Manager or not, if the billing administrator for all subscriptions could be the same, and if billing was consolidated for all company subscriptions. In effect a Subscription would be a Resource mode container. One problem I have, as a software designer, is the accountant is complaining about multiple bills for the same 'service' (Azure).